# onClick event fires infinite when passing a parameter

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have made my first component. The goal is to create a simple dropdown. Every time I add a parameter the click event is fired infinitely:

```
onClick={dropDownChanged(10)}
```

If I call it like below then the event is fired when clicked, but then I don't get the value needed:

```
onClick={dropDownChanged}
```

How do I pass my value so I can update the dropdown with the selected value? I also tried not using an arrow function, but same behaviour.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  Button
} from "reactstrap";

const DropdownPaging = props => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  const dropDownChanged = val => {
    alert("ff");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <Button outline color="dark">
              &lt;
            </Button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Button outline color="dark">
              &gt;
            </Button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
              <DropdownToggle caret outline color="dark">
                10
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem onClick={dropDownChanged}>10</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={dropDownChanged}>25</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={dropDownChanged}>50</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={dropDownChanged}>100</DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropdownPaging;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the function in like this

```
onClick={() => dropDownChanged(10)}
```

Comment: Worked thanks. I will mark as answer when possible.

Comment: No issue, for further reading check out the React docs about functions it covers these cases plus pros and cons: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: I changed the arrow function according to the article to normal function. I took a course on pluralsight that states the making components should almost always be Functions instead of classes. However most samples on the net is classes.

Comment: It depends on what your building and how new the examples are. Currently maintaining three React apps, and nearly all of it uses functions because we have picked up hooks and just run with it. There is no right or wrong over functions or classes but React docs do state with new projects try to use functions and hooks over classes.

Comment: Ok makes sence thanks. One last question :D According to your article using normal functions over arrow function is better for performance as arrow functions creates an instance. What about the way you suggest where you call the function using an arrow function. Would that also impact performance? Or is it only if your event function it selv is an arrow function?

Comment: It does impact performance, yes but not massively, sometimes it's your only choice when you need to pass a parameter. As the docs say if you try to improve performance or improve performance around strict identity comparison you might need to try something else but in most cases it's fine.

Comment: No issue, any time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between giving it as

`onClick={ dropDownChanged(10) }`

and

`onClick={ dropDownChanged }`

In **case 1:** The code invokes the function as soon as that part of code is ran. ie. When the component is rendered, the function is automatically invoked, which leads to unexpected behaviours.

In **case 2:** The function is being passed as reference. This is correct way os passing a function to a click handler but it will be invoked when the button is clicked. But the problem with this approach is that we can not send the value when we invoke the function.

The **ideal solution** in this usecase is to pass a callback function to the event handler.

ie. `onClick={() => dropDownChanged(10)}`

When the button is clicked, it inturn invokes the callback function and works as expected. Hope this clarifies the behavior of event handlers !

Comment: I does thanks. Alexander was a little faster with the answer, but thanks alot for your input. Appreciated.